# Tag user in a facebook post with javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying tag a user in a post with th code below:

```
 FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { 
               message: 'Mensagem':1:Tagged Name]', name:'Test', description:"Test", 
                picture:"picture_address",
                 place:'188587531174763', tags: $("#friendId").val()}, function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
              }
            });
```

The post works perfectly, but the user is not tagged! What is wrong in my code?? Thanks!!!!